# Proving $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2$ via mathematical induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Prove by mathematical induction that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
holds $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

(1) Assume that $n=1$. Then  left side is $1^2 =1$ and right side is $6/6 = 1$, so both sided are equal and expression holds for $n = 1$.

(2) Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is given. Assume that for $n = k$ expression holds. Then for $n = k+1$ we get
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{k+1} i^2 = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{k} i^2\right) + (k+1)^2 = \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} + k^2 + 2k + 1 = \frac{2k^3 + 9k^2 + 13k + 6}{6}.$$
Factoring the result we get that $\frac{2k^3 + 9k^2 + 13k + 6}{6} = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$ and thus expression holds for $n = k+1$.

Combining (1) and (2) we can conclude that the expression holds $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

I have a few questions:

1. Is my proof correct?
2. If you would be a math professor, is this style of writing math proofs right and sufficient for freshman? Or is there something I miss?

Comment: (1) Yes, completely. (2) I am, and I think your proof, as is written, is not only enough but in fact neater and clearer than what I many times see.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks. It was just, that they didn't teach us math induction at our HS, and our uni requires knowledge of it. So I was just asking, if I'm not missing anything. :-)

Comment: Minor corrections: Instead of "Assume that $n=1$" I would say "If $n=1$ then" or similar. It sound strange to use "assume" here.

Comment: Try proving that $\sum_{k=1}^nk(k+1)(k+2)\dots(k+p)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+p)(n+p+1)}{p+2}$ by induction.

Answer (score 0):

we have to show that $$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+(n+1)^2=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$$
this is true since $$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+(n+1)^2$$ is the same as the right-hand side after some algebra

Answer (score 0):

I believe that my answer is implicit in previous, but I tell you that since the factor $(k+1)$ should be in your final formula (I say the factor $(n+1)$ in main formula), you know it since your proof is by induction, and such factor was in each summand $\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$ and $(k+1)^2$ then I believe that **is better strategy to calculate this sum as** $$(k+1)\cdot\text{something}$$ and obtain your result factoring $\text{something}$, since is a polynomial in $k$ of degree $2$. Notice that your factorisation requires solve a polynomial of degree three. Thus **your proof is right**, and you can think about this detail if you think that could be useful next time (I am saying that such factor is a guide to get the final statement).